# How do I set up a delay mid-function?

Tags: unity

I'm trying to set up a delay so that the UI element I'm using to darken and obscure the player's buttons doesn't disappear the second the enemy begins their turn.

Any help would be very appreciated, as I'm super-new and probably making a bit of a hash of things.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TurnController : MonoBehaviour {

static bool playerTurn;
public static GameObject ControlBlocker;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    playerTurn = true;
    ControlBlocker = GameObject.Find("Control Blocker");
    UIController();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

public static void TurnChange()
{
    if (playerTurn == true)
    {
        playerTurn = false;
        UIController();
    }
    else if(playerTurn == false)
    {
        playerTurn = true;
        UIController();
    }
}

public static void UIController()
{
    if (playerTurn == true)
    {
        print("PlayerTurn");
        //Delay here/////////////////////////////////////////
        ControlBlocker.SetActive(false);
    }
    else if (playerTurn == false)
    {
        print("EnemyTurn");
        ControlBlocker.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

EDIT

So after some Google-fu I've made some changes that allow the code to compile with what looks like a working co-routine;

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TurnController : MonoBehaviour {

public static TurnController instance;
static bool playerTurn = true;
public static GameObject ControlBlocker;


private void Awake()
{
    instance = this;
}

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    ControlBlocker = GameObject.Find("Control Blocker");
    ControlBlocker.SetActive(false);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

public static void TurnChange()
{
    if (playerTurn == true)
    {
        playerTurn = false;
        print("TCnowFalse");
        instance.StartCoroutine(UIController());
    }
    else if(playerTurn == false)
    {
        playerTurn = true;
        print("TCnowTrue");
        UIController();
    }
}

public static IEnumerator UIController()
{
    if (playerTurn == true)
    {
        print("PlayerTurn");
        //Delay here
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
        ControlBlocker.SetActive(false);
    }
    else if (playerTurn == false)
    {
        print("EnemyTurn");
        ControlBlocker.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

BUT - Even with this the functionality still isn't working.

The playerTurn == true section of UIController never fires. PlayerTurn never prints to console and the ControlBlocker stays in place.

playerTurn == false works fine however, and TurnChange is working fine too as it prints both messages to the console when appropriate.

Stuck again!

Comment: Do you want your action to happen after a specific time, or are you looking for a fade effect?

Comment: A specific time. The problem at the moment is that as soon as the enemy starts their attack the player UI is enabled again, allowing the player to issue commands and overlap the animations.

Answer (score 1):

Generally this kind of functionality is achieved through Coroutines (functions that can "pause," yielding their execution to later frames).

Here's Unity's documentation explaining what they are / how to use them. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html

Your function as a coroutine would look like this:

```
public static IEnumerator UIController()
{
    if (playerTurn == true)
    {
        print("PlayerTurn");
        yield return null; //Different types of delays, including WaitForSeconds are available. See the docs for how they're used
        ControlBlocker.SetActive(false);
    }
    else if (playerTurn == false)
    {
        print("EnemyTurn");
        ControlBlocker.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Just make sure to call it using "StartCoroutine()" rather than calling the function outright.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, I'd tried something very similar without realising I needed the "StartCoroutine()' part. I guess my question now is how do I use StartCoroutine from inside TurnChange?

Comment: If you want TurnChange to also pause while UIController does its work, then you'd make TurnChange a coroutine too and `yield return StartCoroutine(UIController);` when you want to chain execution to the nested coroutine.